# Case insensitive Basic Authentication with Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, http

Is it possible to configure an Apache server to accept **case insensitive usernames** for Basic Authentication?

Currently I'm using a pattern similar to this (in an included file) in my `httpd.conf`

```
<Location "/admin/">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Admin Area"
   AuthUserFile "/path/to/auth-file"
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Passwords should still be case sensitive.

Comment: Did you ask the same question here and on SO ?

Comment: I thought it better suited to super user and deleted the one on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you can make your auth-file usernames in the same case. Let's say they are uppercase.

To acheive what you want I would :

1. use mod_rewrite with a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) that would call a python (or other) script
2. in the script,

   2. base64 decode the Authentication header
   3. make the user name uppercase (the part before the colunm)
   4. base64 encode the Authentication header
3. Use the new uppercase'd Authentication header

I don't have the setup to test it, but to give you a head start, here is a Python script that implements the idea (emphasis in clarity, it could be shorter) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import base64
import sys
import string

#Get the header value
header = sys.stdin.readline()

#Base 64 decode it
authentication = base64.b64decode(header)

#Split username and password
userpass = authentication.split(':')

#Make username uppercase
userpass[0] = userpass[0].upper()

#Rebuild the authentication with the upper case username
authentication =  string.join(userpass,':')

#Send the base64 result back
print (base64.b64encode(authentication))
```

For a [well known password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example) :

```
$ echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | openssl base64 -d
Aladdin:open sesame
```

The script makes the username uppercase :

```
$ echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | python uppercase_basic.py
QUxBRERJTjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

$ echo QUxBRERJTjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | openssl base64 -d
ALADDIN:open sesame
```

Caveat : this code will fail if you have non-ascii characters in the user name. `étudiant78` becomes `éTUDIANT78` on my machine.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. The second bit I understood no trouble coming from a programming background. The RewriteMap threw me for a bit, but your link and Google helped =]

Comment: How would you configure Apache with `RewriteMap` and `RewriteRule` to **modify** the username (in step 1 and 3)? I have a program for step 2 but from `stdin` I only get URL paths.