# modify apache authorization header with custom program

Tags: apache-http-server

I have an Apache web server which uses Basic Auth with LDAP backend to authenticate users.  Matching of the username against LDAP is case-insensitive, so the same user can login as `abc`, `Abc`, `ABC`, etc.

But the application behind Apache - which I can't change - uses this username in a case-sensitive way, which leads to inconsistent data.

I found an old question with answer which indicate this can be solved by modifying the `Authorization` header with some Apache configuration and a custom program used as `RewriteMap`: [Case insensitive Basic Authentication with Apache](https://superuser.com/questions/429729/case-insensitive-basic-authentication-with-apache)

So I wrote a program to transform the base64-encoded `UsEr:PaSs` values to `user:PaSs`, but I don't know how to integrate it in the Apache configuration.

I tried to use the map with `RewriteRule` or `RequestHeader`, but it doesn't work this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap UserToLower "prg:C:/apache/UserToLower.exe"

# RequestHeader set Authorization "${UserToLower:%{HTTP:Authorization}}"
# RewriteRule "(.*)" "${UserToLower:%{HTTP:Authorization}}"
```

Thanks for any help on this!

I know there is another way to do it with a Perl script to manipulate headers.  But I don't like that solution because then I would need to install Perl and an additional Apache module.

---

### Edit

With Gerard's answer I was able to modify the `Authorization` header.  I couldn't get Apache to accept a modified header.  So instead of fixing the username by converting it to lowercase, users with uppercase letters in their username are now just rejected.  This ensures data integrity so I'm happy with this workaround.

Here's the C# code I used for the rewrite map:

```
/*
 * compile with:
 * C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:winexe UserToLower.cs
 */

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

/**
 * Map username in HTTP Basic Auth to lowercase.
 */
class UserToLower {

    static string decode(string encoded) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
        string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);
        return decodedString;
    }

    static string encode(string decoded) {
        byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decoded);
        string encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedBytes);
        return encodedString;
    }

    static string modifyAuth(string encodedAuthStr) {
        string[] parts = decode(encodedAuthStr).Split(':');
        parts[0] = parts[0].ToLower();
        string newAuthString = encode(String.Join(":", parts));
        return newAuthString;
    }

    static void Main() {
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
            string result;
            if (line.StartsWith("Basic ")) {
                try {
                    result = "Basic " + modifyAuth(line.Substring(6)) + '\n';
                } catch {
                    result = line + '\n';
                }

                // FIXME: remove this hack which keeps out users with unacceptable username
                if (line + '\n' != result) {
                    result = "Basic SU5WQUxJRDpJTlZBTElECg==\n";  // INVALID:INVALID
                }

            } else {
                result = line + '\n';
            }
            Console.Write(result);
            // File.AppendAllText(@"logs/UserToLower.log", line + " ---> " + result);
        }
    }

}
```

And that is my Apache config:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
<IfModule headers_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap UserToLower "prg:C:/apache/UserToLower.exe"
RewriteRule .* - [E=EX:${UserToLower:%{http:Authorization}}]
RequestHeader set Authorization "%{EX}e"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could it be that rewriting only affect the URL, while you need to modify the authorization header?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the referenced answer says there is a way oft doing this.

Comment: I bet it is by using mod_headers.  What do you think?

Comment: I tried to combine `RequestHeader` with the `RewriteMap` (see above) but it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: I believe you'll find a solution here: [how-to-base64-encode-apache-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032461/how-to-base64-encode-apache-header)

Comment: I'd like to know if your rewritemap did function.  I wonder also about the "+ '\n'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following RewriteMap  /usr/local/bin/X.sh:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
typeset -u XU
while read X
do
  XD=$(expr "$X" : "Basic \(.*\)" | base64 -d)
  XU=$(expr "$XD" : "\(.*\):")
  XP=$(expr "$XD" : ".*:\(.*\)")
  XN="Basic $(echo $XU:$XP | base64)"
  echo "${XN}"
done
```

and the following Apache configuration

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap rmx "prg:/usr/local/bin/X.sh"

    <Location ~ "(?i)php$">
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "phprivate area"
        AuthUserFile    "/etc/apache2/passwd"
        Require            valid-user

        RewriteRule .* - [E=EX:${rmx:%{http:Authorization}}]

        RequestHeader set Authorization %{EX}e
    </Location>
```

the username was changed to uppercase.

Comment: The opposite of "typeset -u" is "typeset -l".  ;-)